# Testing that an on demand nexmo notification has been sent

Tags: laravel

I think that I should be able to do this, using something similar to this:

```
Notification::assertSentTo(new AnonymousNotifiable(), Notification::class, function($notification, $channels, $notifiable){
            return $notifiable->routes['mail'] == 'mail@yahoo.com';
        });
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21379

But I'm not sure how to use it for a nexmo route, I'm trying something like this:

```
Notification::assertSentTo(new AnonymousNotifiable(), Notification::class, function($notification, $channels, $notifiable){
            return $notifiable->routes['nexmo'] == '12345';
        });
```

I get, "The expected [Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification] notification was not sent. Failed asserting that false is true."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working like this:

```
Notification::assertSentTo(new AnonymousNotifiable(), SMS::class, function($notification, $channels, $notifiable) use ($toNumber){
            return $notifiable->routes['nexmo'] == $toNumber;
        });
```